# Sistema em Java enviando mensagem para celular

Tags: primefaces, hibernate, java, sms

Fala pessoal, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java web com Eclipse Maven, para utilizar em um pequeno escritório, sistema rodara na nuvem e o acesso por computadores do escritório. Me foi solicitado ao finalizar um lançamento, que um usuário determinado receba um sms em seu celular cadastrado pelo sistema, com informações referente a atividade realizada pelo sistema.
Seria algo parecido quando recebemos sms da agencia do banco informando, cada movimentação da conta.
Obrigado se alguem puder me ajudar. 
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Caro Silvano, sua dúvida não está especificada, o que você deseja fazer? Quer dicas por onde começar, como fazer? Até onde você sabe? Desta maneira podemos te ajudar melhor.

Existem algumas maneiras de se fazer isso:

1) Chamando um web service/API (maneira mais fácil)

- Pesquise por sms gateway ou sms api (Existem empresas especializadas neste tipo de serviço no Brasil, infelizmente só conheço as empresas da Espanha que é onde eu moro, caso precise de ajuda para procurar comenta abaixo que eu te ajudo.) Fiz uma rápida consulta no google por "serviço de envio de sms" e vi diversas opções em php, javascript e outras linguagens e adaptar para java não seria problema por se tratar normalmente por chamadas http.

2) Criando um servidor conectado a um celular, como você disse que ficara na nuvem seria inviável isso.

Como este:

- http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=584

**Caso** seu sms necessite possuir validez legal, que hoje em dia está super em alta, voce poderia tentar contratar a Certising onde utiliza os serviços da empresa onde trabalho Lleida.net para enviar sms e emails certificados.